# Conjugate function with scaling and composition with affine transformation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Conjugate of a function $f(x)$ is defined as $$f^*(y)=\sup_{x~\in ~dom~f} \{y^Tx-f(x)\}.$$ If $g(x)=f(Ax+b)$ then how to show that $$g^*(y)=f^*(A^{-T}y)-b^TA^{-T}y,~~~~(1)$$ where $A^{-T}=(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$ and $A$ is positive definite.

My Attempt:

We know that left side of $(1)$ is $$\sup_{x~\in~dom~g}\{y^Tx-g(x)\}=\sup_{Ax+b~\in~dom~f}\{y^Tx-f(Ax+b)\}.~~~(2)$$ Now the right hand side of $(1)$ is $$f^*(A^{-T}y)-b^TA^{-T}y=\sup_{x~\in~dom~f}\{y^TA^{-1}x-f(x)\}-b^TA^{-T}y~~~(3)$$ Now how to show that the right hand sides of $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equal? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ide is much simpler. You can make a change of variables $z=Ax+b$. Because $A$ is invertible, it is equivalent to $x=A^{-1}(z-b)$. Perform this substitution in the supremum and in a few steps you are done.

Comment: Thank you. Your idea works for getting right side of (3) from the right side of (2). I think if we use $x=As+b$ in right side of (3) then again we will end up in getting the right side of (2). Thanks again for your comment it gave me another option to solve it :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $f$ is proper we can simplify life by extending $f$ to have the
value $+\infty$ for $x \notin \operatorname{dom} f$.

Then $f^*(y) = \sup_x (y^T x - f(x))$ and so
\begin{eqnarray}
g^*(x) &=& \sup_x (y^T x - f(Ax+b)) \\
&=& \sup_x (y^T (A^{-1}x) - f(x+b)) \\
&=& \sup_x ((A^{-T}y)^T (x) - f(x+b)) \\
&=& \sup_x ((A^{-T}y)^T (x-b) - f(x)) \\
&=& \sup_x ((A^{-T}y)^T x - f(x)) - (A^{-T}y)^T b\\
&=& f^*(A^{-T}y) - (A^{-T}y)^T b\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do you define proper here?

Comment: The epigraph is non empty and contains no vertical lines (so the subtraction is meaningful). Proper is a standard term in convex analysis.